# Eclipse Juno project facets does not recognize that I have Java 1.6

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2

I have an Eclipse/Maven web project. I'm trying to update the facets to support JSF2. However I can't update the dynamic web module to 3.0 (or even 2.5) because Eclipse refuses to recognize that I'm using Java 1.6. It shows Java 1.6 in the facet properties, but every time I try to change the dynamic web module to 2.5 or 3.0, it tells me I must use Java 1.6 even though that is selected. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if and how Maven plays a role here, but ignoring that, you can alternatively also change the project facets by editing the `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` file. You can find the file when you browse in *Navigator* view (instead of *Project Explorer*). To set the dynamic web project facet version to 3.0, edit the following entry (with an unknown version, represented by `...`)

```
<installed facet="jst.web" version="..."/>
```

to

```
<installed facet="jst.web" version="3.0"/>
```

If that doesn't solve the concrete problem, then most probably some Maven plugin has forced the facet versions based on a `pom.xml` or so.

Comment: Thanks (my previous comments weren't posted??).

Comment: Thanks-- this solved my problem of not being able to select 1.8 in the Java facet's version dropdown. (Note that this was only for my dynamic web project; other projects did not have this problem.)

After editing, restart Eclipse.Then I recommend opening the Facet's preference pane and click Apply or OK. This lets Eclipse sanity check the setting you edited. In my case it reported that my deploy server (Tomcat) was still on Java 1.7. (This might have been the root cause of the facet problem for me, but I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, looked at the .project file of my maven/eclipse project. 
Turned out, that you have to first make the Project a Java project in your Project facet project preferences page!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of right now, Eclipse Java EE tooling does not support changing spec versions on module facets (ear, ejb, web, etc.). You can edit the metadata file directly as BalusC has described and patch up any other source compatibility issues. Alternatively, you can create a new project with the appropriate spec version and copy you source into it.

Answer (score 0):

If like me you find that only your Dynamic Web projects have this problem, try checking whether the server you are deploying to is configured for the JRE version you want.  (Global Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments; then edit the server runtime environment in question.)

You may also need to manually edit your Eclipse settings, as suggested by BalusC and Konstantin. If you do, after restarting Eclipse re-open the Facets preference pane and click OK or Apply. This lets Eclipse sanity check your new setting.